# I could not find json file in OSMBuilding

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geojson

I make clickable buildings with OSM Buildings. When I click a building, I get Building ID. However, I could not get height of a building because I cannot fing JSON file to get this value.

Codes are here:

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
map.setView([52.52111, 13.40988], 16, false);
new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com ...
```

https://codepen.io/osmbuildings/pen/JdaaRM

To sum up, I want to get height of a building with using OSM Building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height *is* contained in the JSON file.

See this example here: https://b.data.osmbuildings.org/0.2/anonymous/tile/16/35210/21491.json. It contains a `properties` field which in turn contains `height` and `levels`:

```
"id": "w24273225",
"type": "Feature",
"properties": {
  "height": 65,
  "levels": 17
},
"geometry": {
  "type": "Polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [...]
  ]
}
```

The height and level information is only present if the building in OSM actually has this information. This isn't the case for every building.